# In coo_matrix (scipy sparse matrix), how can I select and return "random column index" in each row excluding non-zero indexes in that row?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am new to Python and this may seem to be pretty naive. I am working with coo_matrix (scipy sparse matrix) **M** and want to return triplets of M:

```
row_index,column_index,random_index
```

with following conditions:

1. row_index,column_index must point to a non-zero entry of M
2. row_index,column_index corresponding to all non-zero entries should be returned
3. For each pair of row_index,column_index, random_index should be returned
4. random_index should be in the range of [0,total_num_columns] of M
5. random_index should not be in the set of all the column indices which point to some non-zero value for that row_index

I could come up with following function:

```
 def get_triplets(M):
return M.row, M.col, np.random.randint(M.shape[1], size=len(M.row))
```

Everything works fine in the above function except last entry of triplet - **random_index** is not in desired way. It is not guaranteed that random index will not lie in set of non-zero indices for that row. In other words, condition number (5) is not satisfied

Is there an efficient way of returning triplets meeting all the above mentioned 5 conditions. Hoping that I could make myself clear and I appreciate any help in solving my problem

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a coo matrix `M`, `M.row`, `M.col` and `M.data` are the 3 arrays that define the matrix, and together identify all nonzero entries.  They may be unordered, and they may contain duplicates.

```
In [1]: from scipy import sparse
In [2]: row=[0,0,1,1,1,2,2]
In [3]: col=[0,2,0,1,0,1,2]
In [4]: data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
In [5]: M=sparse.coo_matrix((data,(row,col)))
In [6]: M
Out[6]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 7 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [7]: print(M)
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 2)    2
  (1, 0)    3
  (1, 1)    4
  (1, 0)    5
  (2, 1)    6
  (2, 2)    7
In [8]: M.A
Out[8]: 
array([[1, 0, 2],
       [8, 4, 0],
       [0, 6, 7]])
```

We can make it canonical - sorted without duplicates with:

```
In [9]: M.sum_duplicates()
In [10]: print(M)
  (0, 0)    1
  (1, 0)    8
  (1, 1)    4
  (2, 1)    6
  (0, 2)    2
  (2, 2)    7
```

This, by the way, is a step toward converting to the `csr` format.

(Opps - that is lex sorted by column first)

---

If I picture the random bit correctly, you want, for each non-zero entry, a random selection from the zero-slots of the same row.  I'll assume we don't care whether there are repeeats.

So we need to colect all rows together.
 This might be easier with the `lil` format

```
In [13]: Ml = M.tolil()
In [14]: Ml.data
Out[14]: array([[1, 2], [8, 4], [6, 7]], dtype=object)
In [16]: Ml.rows
Out[16]: array([[0, 2], [0, 1], [1, 2]], dtype=object)
```

Just iterate on each list in `Ml.rows` and generate the random selection.

---

Here's a start:

```
def foo(cols, N):
    c = set(range(N))
    c = c.difference(cols)
    return np.random.choice(list(c))
In [29]: [foo(c,3) for c in Ml.rows]
Out[29]: [1, 2, 0]
```

Not quite what we want; it picks a zero column for each row.  In this example there is only one per row.

Change `choice` to return multiple values per call:

```
def foo(cols, N):
    c = set(range(N))
    c = c.difference(cols)
    return np.random.choice(list(c),size=len(cols), replace=True)

In [32]: [foo(c,3) for c in Ml.rows]
Out[32]: [array([1, 1]), array([2, 2]), array([0, 0])]
```

We could take those random values, write them back into `Ml` as `data`

```
In [37]: randval = [foo(c,3) for c in Ml.rows]
In [38]: randval
Out[38]: [array([1, 1]), array([2, 2]), array([0, 0])]
In [39]: Ml.data
Out[39]: array([[1, 2], [8, 4], [6, 7]], dtype=object)
In [40]: Ml.data[:] = randval
In [41]: Ml.data
Out[41]: array([array([1, 1]), array([2, 2]), array([0, 0])], dtype=object)
In [42]: Ml.A
Out[42]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)

In [45]: print(Ml)
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 2)    1
  (1, 0)    2
  (1, 1)    2
  (2, 1)    0
  (2, 2)    0

In [48]: Mo=Ml.tocoo()
In [51]: np.column_stack((Mo.row, Mo.col, Mo.data))
Out[51]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [2, 2, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

This display would be more meaningful if the array was larger with multiple zero columns per row.  Also my code will break if any row is dense (no zeros).

So all together

```
In [56]: M=sparse.rand(10,10,.2,'coo')
In [58]: Ml=M.tolil()
In [59]: randval = [foo(c,Ml.shape[1]) for c in Ml.rows]
In [61]: Ml.data[:] = randval
In [62]: Mo=Ml.tocoo()
In [63]: np.column_stack((Mo.row, Mo.col, Mo.data))
```

---

Copied from your comment, for ease of formatting

> Originally, I had this function:

```
def get_triplets(M): 
   return M.row, M.col, np.random.randint(M.shape[1], size=len(M.row))
```

> And it works in time but is not consistent. But now:

```
def get_triplets(mat): 
     M1 = mat.tolil() 
     randval = [foo(c, M1.shape[1]) for c in M1.rows] 
     M1.data[:] = randval 
     Mo = M1.tocoo() 
     return_mat = np.column_stack((Mo.row, Mo.col, Mo.data)) 
     return return_mat[:, 0], return_mat[:, 1], return_mat[:, 2]
```

Comment: To confirm in the function: `return_mat = np.column_stack((Mo.row, Mo.col, Mo.data)) return return_mat[:, 0], return_mat[:, 1], return_mat[:, 2]`

Comment: but, this operation seems to be extremely time consuming. Is there an optimized way of doing this that you know of? Should I ask a separate question for that?

Comment: What kind of optimization are you hoping for?  By your specification we have to work row by row.   What is slowing this down?  conversion to/form `lil`?  Row iteration?  `foo`?    I chose the `lil` format because it is easy to use and demonstrate.  `csr` row iteration is also possible, but more complex.

Comment: I am not sure. The full operation takes huge amounts of time ~ 72 hours for a file of size: 80MB. And I had to stop the operation. Originally, I had this function: ` def get_triplets(M):
return M.row, M.col, np.random.randint(M.shape[1], size=len(M.row))`. And it works in time but is not consistent. But now: def get_triplets(mat):
    M1 = mat.tolil()
    randval = [foo(c, M1.shape[1]) for c in M1.rows]
    M1.data[:] = randval
    Mo = M1.tocoo()
    return_mat = np.column_stack((Mo.row, Mo.col, Mo.data))
    return return_mat[:, 0], return_mat[:, 1], return_mat[:, 2]

Comment: It's your 5th condition that forces us to work row by row.  Ignore that, and it is trivial to generate the random indices.  Maybe you need to step back and explain why you need such numbers in the first place.  I can't imagine a realistic scenario.